# Active page link icon color

Tags: javascript, css

Hi everyone i have one question about active page link color.

I am using this javascript code for active page link.

```
$(".header a").filter(function(){
    return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
}).addClass("header_active_link");
```

this is CSS code

```
.header{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
.icon{
   margin:0;
   margin-right:10px;
   padding:13px;
   height:23px;
   width:23px;
   color:blue;
   overflow:hidden;
   float:left;
   font-size:24px;
}
.icon-compass-2:before {
   content: "\e08b";
}
.header_active_link{
   color: #ffffff;
    }
```

and this is HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <a href="<?php echo $main_url.'about/'; ?>"><div class="icon icon-compass-2"></div></a>
</div>
```

In CSS code `.icon` color is main color. When user click about link then it needs to change text color `color:blue;` to `color:#ffffff;` but not changing. What can i do for changing icon color ?

Answer (score 0):

you could use  the [CSS :active Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

```
.header a:active { 
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and do this:

```
$('.header a').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('.header_active_link');
});
```